# .off() clearing the cache of all ref's?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I have multiple listeners on the same location, will all listeners access the same local cache or does every listener has it's own "copy" of the cache? And what happens to the cache when I use `.off()` to remove one of those listeners? Will the local cache be removed and repopulated again through the other listeners (since they still listen for changes)?

My understanding is that all listeners use the same local cache of a location, but when I use `.off()` only the listener and it's code gets removed, but the data stays in the memory.

```
var applyUpdate1 = function(snap) {
  //...
};
var applyUpdate2 = function(snap) {
  //...
};

// Both sync data from the same location
var testRef1 = firebase.database().ref('test').on('value', applyUpdate1);
var testRef2 = firebase.database().ref('test').on('value', applyUpdate2);

// Will this delete the local memory?
// If so, what happens to testRef2, since it's using this local memory?
testRef1.off('value', applyUpdate1);
```

I also modified my understanding of it above. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Answer to your first question is below. I don't understand your second question. It sounds like something that will be easier to answer if you show the [minimum code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for it.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I added the minimum code. I hope it helps.

Comment: I added the answer for your second question too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If multiple listeners are observing the same location, the data is only read/synchronized from the server once and only kept in memory once.

As long as there are any active listeners on a location, the data for that location is kept in memory. When the last active listener for a location is removed, the data for that location is immediately cleared from memory.